# Play a movie in the desktop as a wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background, video-player

I was wondering is there a way to play movies in the desktop,like a background?or is it not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to do just this:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/dreamscene-for-ubuntu-ta-very-much/

Comment: This s out of date, is there a more applicable method/tutorial? xwinwrap is not at the supplied link.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Windows using VLC, I don't know if it is possible in Ubuntu, but here are the directions in Windows, could be the same process, I just don't know.

http://lifehacker.com/5549671/set-a-video-as-your-wallpaper-with-vlc