# Ubuntu Equivalent to Dreamscapes?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, desktop-background, wmv

In Windows Vista Ultimate, there was a feature called [DreamScapes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/About-Windows-DreamScene) that let you set any wmv file as your desktop background and thereby have a moving desktop. There was a program that let users of Windows 7 and other Windows OSs use dreamscapes by editing registiry values. Is there any way I can set up a moving desktop similar to a dreamscapes in Ubuntu 11.10? If so, how? If not, is there any similar feature in Ubuntu? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using Unity and therefore the answer 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7351/play-a-movie-in-the-desktop-as-a-wallpaper) doesn't work.

Comment: Similar question as this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/7351/play-a-movie-in-the-desktop-as-a-wallpaper) - in my testing, this solution still works in Gnome-Classic but doesnt work in the unity-desktop :(

Comment: Well, unfortanately I need it to work in Unity. Sorry :)

Comment: please reword your question to link to the other and make it clear you need to work in unity-desktop and not just gnome-classic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the neatest programs out there to do just what you are asking is called electric sheep. It works in Unity and Gnome3. If you do a Google search you will learn more about what it . 
You need to install xwinwrap and xscreensaver in order for the program to work.Most of the stuff you will read shows it as a screensaver but using xwinwrap it can be set up as a backdrop for your desktop . I pipe it to my big screen from the computer and can sit for hours watching it. Go to the electric sheep website first and then here for specific instructions for Unity or gnome 3 installation.

[electricsheep screensaver won't start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61305/electricsheep-screensaver-wont-start)

After installing electric sheep and xwinwrap this will run it.

xwinwrap -ni  -fs -s -st -sp -b -nf -- /usr/lib/xscreensaver/electricsheep -window-id WID

Comment: electicsheep + xscreensaver does work in natty & oneiric - but have you managed to get xwinwrap + electricsheep to work with the unity desktop on 11.10 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. I will find out if this works in 11.10 and report back.