# Use video for wallpaper

Tags: unity, 13.04, video, desktop-background

How can I use a video as my desktop wallpaper? I would like to have it like normal wallpaper so the icons etc. sit on top of it, just as in a static wallpaper picture.

A similar question was asked at [How do I set a VLC instance to run as a Live Wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58657/how-do-i-set-a-vlc-instance-to-run-as-a-live-wallpaper) but no answer was given that support icons, for example, it seems.

Comment: Same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/174362/installing-live-wallpapers-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @fossfreedom To be honest I am not sure. If you follow the links you get "IMPORTANT: The development of these compiz plugins stopped. You can find a new version of the live wallpapers which don't require compiz here: https://launchpad.net/livewallpaper " and then you see that live wallpaper doesn't seem to support playing arbitrary videos.  I could be wrong of course...

Comment: Or this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7351/play-a-movie-in-the-desktop-as-a-wallpaper But it is NOT possible with icons. You need to use something like screenlets instead of icons.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you. That is three years old. Maybe something has changed since then?

Comment: Nope @felix it is not possible due to the way the desktop is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [anibg](http://code.google.com/p/anibg/),
 xwinwrap, [gwinwrap](http://code.google.com/p/gwinwrap/)